# What do we actually mean by "State" in State management?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, state-management

Can anyone please explain in simple terms, what is a State and what is State Management?
(I'm using Flutter but I'm open to both general and Flutter/Dart specific answers)

I'm just trying to learn the core idea behind the concept.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site to ask question like this, It is strictly used for helping others with the issues in their code.

Comment: I'm having an issue with my code because I need to use state management but I couldn't completely understand what it was, so I decided to ask here, where someone who knows can help me understand. I don't think my question was out of concept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In its most general form, state is the everything that would need to be restored to return to a particular point in time. The scope also has to be defined, since it's not reasonable to move planets backwards in their orbits, so you'll generally have an app state, or a widget state, or possibly separate states within an app (a game board that changes while the high score section doesn't until the game ends with a new high score).

The Flutter documentation is a pretty good description on what it is, why, and how to do it:

https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Often changes to the state are stored in a buffer allowing you to undo them or redo them in sequence, or they can be saved as a checkpoint to restart after a crash or forced quit/suspend (depends on the app environment).